# How can I do a loop using promises with nodejs and zombie.js

Tags: node.js, zombie.js

I am working with zombie.js, and I need to click a button until the button has got some text in the "style" attribute (the button changes after every click).

I use this structure.

```
     browser
    .visit(url)
    .then(function() {    
        console.log("Scraping ...");            
        ...
    })
    .then(function() {
        var button = browser.query([SELECTOR]);             
        if(button != null)
        {
            if(button.outerHTML.indexOf([TEXT_TO_SEEK]) == -1)
            {
                console.log("Click more button");
                return browser.pressButton([SELECTOR]);
            }                       
        }
        return;
    })
```

It works for one time, but I want to execute this n-times until the condition was satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

This recursive one works for me:

```
browser
    .visit(url)
    .then(function () {
        console.log('Scraping ...');
        //...
    })
    .then(function () {
        var maxClicks = 10;
        return (function pressIt() {
            if (maxClicks-- <= 0) {
                throw new Error('Usless button');
            }

            var button = browser.query([SELECTOR]);
            if (!button) {
                throw new Error('There is no button');
            }

            if (button.outerHTML.indexOf([TEXT_TO_SEEK]) == -1) {
                console.log('Click more button');
                return browser.pressButton([SELECTOR]).then(pressIt);
            } else {
                return 'This button rocks';
            }
        })();
    }).then(console.log, console.error);
```

output:

```
"Scraping ..."
"Click more button"
"Click more button"
"Click more button"
"This button rocks"
```